# XMLHttpRequest works but no response/status back on callback

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, response

I have an `XMLHttpRequest` where i am sending an image across to be saved on my Amazon s3 bucket. It works correctly and the file goes to my bucket but i am getting no response back saying it is in process or has successfully uploaded. My code is below:

Javascript code in html page:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("POST",'http://www.xxxx.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(theImage);

ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {                                           
        console.log('success');  
    }
    else {                                           
        console.log('ongoing...');
    }
}
```

PHP code in xxxx.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
    $imageData = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    $filteredData = substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
    $imgFileString = base64_decode($filteredData);
    $s3Filename = time().'.png';

    if($s3->putObjectString($imgFileString, $bucket , $s3Filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) ){
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    else{
        echo "ERROR";
    }
}
else {
    echo "EMPTY";
}
?>
```

How can i get a callback to say when the upload has successfully been uploaded or if an error has occurred?

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: What does the developer tools net tab say? Did you get a 200 OK response?

Comment: What happens if you add logging to the `readystate` event handler? Log the `readyState` and `status` when you output `"ongoing...." and tell us what values you end up with.

Comment: My javascript console is completely blank, the network tab shows the POST and the status comes in at 200, OK. I added `console.log(ajax.status);` and `console.log(ajax.readyState);` in the same place as 'ongoing..' and again get nothing output in console.

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest is inside a function that gets called on a button click. One thing i notice is that on clicking it, the button state freezes/hangs on the down state as if i'm still pressing on it. The upload carries on fine and it's only for 3-4 seconds until reverts back to normal but not sure if this has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ajax.open("POST",'http://www.xxxx.php',false);
                                       ^^^^^^
```

You are making a synchronous request, so the request is being made and the response received before you assign your event handler. Don't do that. Remove `false` (or change it to `true`).

Comment: Ah how stupid! Thanks so much for spotting that for me, all console logs etc now get outputted as expected